# How __getitem__ is able to convert 1:2 to slice(1,2,None) object

Tags: python, class, slice

I was reading one answer on use of slicing in python, and observed that we can change the `__getitem__` method. As an example he has given the following code.

```
>>> class slicee:
...    def __getitem__(self, item):
...        return item
...
>>> slicee()[1,2,1:2]
(1,2,slice(1,2,None))
```

My problem is-- how can and `__getitem__` convert 1:2 to slice(1,2,None) without any extra method. if we run

```
[1:2], 1:2
```

python will show syntax error.

Comment: `1:2` is not a valid python syntax (outside brackets), you can't do it. You could, however  create slices manually `slice(1,2)`. I believe the conversion is built into CPython's parser.

Comment: @ImanolLuengo, but this does not clear how in `__getitem__`, item is converted to slice object, we also have many elements passed inside `[]`. How is this expression`[1,2,1:2]` interpreted in python. As far as I know, `__getitem__` is called when `[]` is used with instance object.

Comment: Read https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#slicings and/or https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#slicings

Comment: As @Leon suggested, expressions llike `[1,2,1:2]` are automatically parsed by python when you trigger `__getitem__`. There is nothing you can do to simulate it at the Python level.

Comment: If you're interested, the syntax `1:2` in a getitem context triggers the [`BUILD_SLICE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L3447-L3463) opcode. You can see in the C code the line `slice = PySlice_New(start, stop, step)` where the slice object is constructed. It is this object that is the passed to the object's `__getitem__` method. (Sorry I don't have time for a fuller answer now.)

Comment: I am very much thankful for references, @AlexRiley I am trying to understand all the linking(how the whole process is carried out), if  possible, please elaborate on context based parsing.